# Parameter in cloud function using Parse and Angular $resource

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, coffeescript

I am trying to call this [cloud function]..

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getMyData", function(request, response) {
  console.log('request is : '+JSON.stringify(request));
  console.log('parameter is : '+request.params.name);
  //...
  response.success('Run method successfully');
});
```

using Parse REST api from an Angular front end.

```
$resource 'https://api.parse.com/1/functions/getMyData', {},
    myCustomMethod:
      method: 'POST'
      headers:
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'FjV0J.....'
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'Tr7Sipvu....'
      params:
        name: 'William'
```

My cloud function gets called, but I can't seem to retrieve my *name* parameter :

```
I2015-05-16T00:51:08.497Z]request is : {"body":"{}","params":{},"installationId":"","user":null,"master":false}
I2015-05-16T00:51:08.497Z]parameter is : undefined
```

Why doesn't my parameter appear in *params*?
Is there a problem with using Angular `$resource` to make such API calls?

Answer (score 0):

What put me on the right path was that it worked great when using a `curl` call - as documented [here](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#cloud-code-cloud-functions).

In the end, I was able to retrieve my parameter by using `$http` instead of `$resource` :

```
// In controler
$http.post 'https://api.parse.com/1/functions/getMyData'
      ,
        name: 'William'
      ,
        method: 'POST'
        headers:
          'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'FjV0J.....'
          'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'Tr7Sipvu....'
      .success (data) ->
        $scope.data = data
```

It appears Parse expects *parameters* to be transmitted through *data* which isn't possible with Angular `$resource`.